# How to get labels from json file and attach them to images

Tags: json, tensorflow, deep-learning, dataset

I can't access to coordinate data in json file. I need to label images with x and y coordinates from json file. My goal is to train cnn to recognise these keypoints from images. File structure:

```
{
    "Labeled Data": "url",
    "Label": {
      "radius inclination angle": [
        {
          "geometry": {
            "x": 193,
            "y": 222
          }
        },
        {
          "geometry": {
            "x": 242,
            "y": 228
          }
        }
      ],
      "radioulnar ": [
        {
          "geometry": {
            "x": 244,
            "y": 227
          }
        },
        {
          "geometry": {
            "x": 250,
            "y": 225
          }
        }
      ],
      "scapholunar": [
        {
          "geometry": {
            "x": 224,
            "y": 217
          }
        },
        {
          "geometry": {
            "x": 219,
            "y": 217
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

I have tried to access "x" and "y" like this:

```
for item in data:
    for label in item['Label']['radiuksen inklinaatio']:
        for cordinates in label['geometry']:
            print(cordinates)
```

Code above prints only x and y but no their value. If I could get the values then I would make new label with coordinates only. 
The outcome should look like this:

```
[
    {'label': '"x":219, "y"=217...', 'image': 'http://example.com/c1.jpg'},

    ...
]
```

What I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can use json module.

```
import json
with open('file.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
```

In case you need to open file. `data` is a nested combination of lists and dicts depending on particular file. You can access its contents like standard list/dict. For example:

```
data['Label']['radius inclination angle'].append('smth') #use append if particular nested structutre is a list 
data['Label']['radius inclination angle'][0]['smth'] = '123'
print(data['Label']['radius inclination angle'])
```

This will output

```
[{'geometry': {'x': 193, 'y': 222}, 'smth': '123'}, {'geometry': {'x': 242, 'y': 228}}, 'smth']
```

It's not completely clear what exact output you're trying to get from provided example. But I hope this will be enough. You can read more here 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html